# How to get isotope's filtering to work with a jquery fancy box slide show?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jquery-isotope

I have created a gallery using both Jquery Fancybox and Isotope. I have a list of thumbnail images on my page. People can sort the images using some filters I created with Isotope. People can also click a thumbnail to enlarge it using JQuery Fancybox. The problem I have is that when someone sorts the images and then clicks to enlarge the image, the forward and backward buttons in fancybox still cycle through all the images instead of just the filtered images. For example:

If these are my filters:

```
<li class="catOne">Category One</li>
<li class="catTwo">Category Two</li>
```

And These are my images:

```
<div class="isotopeItem catOne">Image goes here</div>
<div class="isotopeItem catOne">Image goes here</div>    
<div class="isotopeItem catTwo">Image goes here</div>    
<div class="isotopeItem catTwo">Image goes here</div>
```

When the user clicks on the CatTwo filter the page shows only the last two images. But if I click the image to see it enlarge with Fancy box, my forward backward buttons bring me through all the images. I would only want it to show the images that have been filtered. I can post all my code here if that makes sense. Was trying to keep things simple. Here is a link to the page I'm talking about. http://www.ce.ryanswansondesign.com/artists/artists/a-f/shelby-lee-adams.html

Comment: You may need to bind an extra `click` event to your filters and pass the value of the filter to the `data-fancybox-group` attribute. You could check this to get an idea how-to http://www.picssel.com/create-a-filtered-image-gallery-with-jquery-and-fancybox/

Answer (score 0):

I Should have searched around more. I found this great solution here: [jQuery Isotope filtering with Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414180/jquery-isotope-filtering-with-fancybox)

Basically the solution has to do with isotope filters. Here is the code that I added to my isotope

```
   $('.filter a').click(function(){
          var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter-value');
      $('#artContent').isotope({ filter: selector }, function(){
        if(selector == "*"){
         $(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery");
        } else{ 
         $(selector).find(".fancybox").attr("data-fancybox-group", selector);
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't get this to work. How do I find out what selector should used? `$('#artContent').isotope({ filter: selector },`
You are using `#artContent`, but since I can't see your HTML, I don't know what I should replace it with.