# jQuery Isotope filtering

Tags: jquery, joomla, jquery-isotope

I have a Joomla site with a bought template containing a portfolio based on isotope and touchtouch
I have the same problem as described on another post - the only difference is that they use fancybox and my template uses touchtouch : [jQuery Isotope filtering with Fancybox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414180/jquery-isotope-filtering-with-fancybox)

Here's the description of the problem :

The portfolio contains a gallery of thumbnails.
You can click on the thumbnails and then cycle trough the images with the touchtouch plugin
Now the thing is, when the gallery is being filtered, the touchtouch plugin still cycles trough all the images. Even the ones who are not showing up when the filter is applied.

I tried to transform the solution of the fancybox-post but still I don't know how I could solve this.

I suppose that one should modify the following script in gallery.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  (function($){ 
   $(window).load(function(){

    var $container = $('#isotopeContainer');

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('#filters a').click(function(){
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
      return false;
    });

    var $optionSets = $('#filters li'),
        $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

        $optionLinks.click(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            // don't proceed if already selected
            if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
              return false;
            }
            var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
            $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $this.addClass('selected');

            // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
            var options = {},
                key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
                value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
            // parse 'false' as false boolean
            value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
            options[ key ] = value;
            if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
              // changes in layout modes need extra logic
              changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
            } else {
              // otherwise, apply new options
              $container.isotope( options );
            }

            return false;
        });
   });
})(jQuery);
}); 
</script>
```

Do you have any Idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm glad to say that I've done it
My first ideas (see previous posts) did not work for me but I have now a better understanding of how it works. 
So I found another way to do it : Now I show the category on the  element and

```
var overlay = $('<div id="galleryOverlay">'),
    slider = $('<div id="gallerySlider">'),
    prevArrow = $('<a id="prevArrow"></a>'),
    nextArrow = $('<a id="nextArrow"></a>'),
    overlayVisible = false;
var gtritems = [];      

/* Creating the plugin */

$.fn.touchTouch = function(){

    var placeholders = $([]),
        index = 0,
        items = this;

    // Appending the markup to the page
    overlay.hide().appendTo('body');
    slider.appendTo(overlay);

    // Creating a placeholder for each image
    items.each(function(){
        placeholders = placeholders.add($('<div class="placeholder">'));
    });

    $("#gallerySlider").empty();
    // Hide the gallery if the background is touched / clicked
    slider.append(placeholders).on('click',function(e){
        if(!$(e.target).is('img')){
            hideOverlay();
        }
    });

    // Listen for touch events on the body and check if they
    // originated in #gallerySlider img - the images in the slider.
    $('body').on('touchstart', '#gallerySlider img', function(e){

        var touch = e.originalEvent,
            startX = touch.changedTouches[0].pageX;

        slider.on('touchmove',function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] ||
                    e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];

            if(touch.pageX - startX > 10){
                slider.off('touchmove');
                showPrevious();
            }
            else if (touch.pageX - startX < -10){
                slider.off('touchmove');
                showNext();
            }
        });

        // Return false to prevent image 
        // highlighting on Android
        return false;

    }).on('touchend',function(){
        slider.off('touchmove');
    });

    // Listening for clicks on the thumbnails

    items.on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        // Find the position of this image
        // in the collection

        function Gtr(obj, href, ind, itemind) {
            this.obj=obj;
            this.href=href;
            this.ind=ind;
            this.itemind=itemind;
            return this;
        }
        gtritems = [];
        var i = 0;
        var oldindex = items.index(this);
        $.each(items, function() {
            if(window.selector == '*'){
                gtritems.push( new Gtr(this, items.eq(items.index(this)).attr('href'), items.index(this), items.index(this)) );
                if(oldindex == items.index(this)) {
                    index = oldindex;
                }
            } else {
                if($(this).attr("class").split(" ",4)[3] == window.selector.substr(1)){
                    gtritems.push( new Gtr(this, items.eq(items.index(this)).attr('href'), i, items.index(this)) );
                    if(oldindex == items.index(this)) {
                        index = i;
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        });
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to make work navigation that takes in account filters but now I have the problem that when the portfolio shows up the first time - before any filtering - the touchtouch plugin does not fire.

Here I show you the code involved :

Gallery.php (part of the template override) :

```
<?php if($this->params->get('show_filter')): ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  (function($){ 
   $(window).load(function(){

    var $container = $('#isotopeContainer');

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('#filters a').click(function(){
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
      if(selector == "*"){
        console.log(selector);
      } else { 
        $(".touchGalleryLink").removeClass("MyCat");
        $(".touchGalleryLink").each(function() {
            var tmpvar = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class').split(" ",2);
            if(tmpvar[1] == selector.substr(1)){
              $(this).addClass("MyCat");
            }
        });
      }
      jQuery('a.touchGalleryLink.MyCat').touchTouch();
      return false;
    });
...
```

In the script.js file I needed to comment out a line :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  ...
  // Initialize the gallery touch
  //jQuery('a.touchGalleryLink').touchTouch();
  ...
```

For Information heres a part of the touch.galery.js file :

```
(function($){

/* Private variables */

var overlay = $('<div id="galleryOverlay">'),
slider = $('<div id="gallerySlider">'),
prevArrow = $('<a id="prevArrow"></a>'),
nextArrow = $('<a id="nextArrow"></a>'),
overlayVisible = false;

/* Creating the plugin */

$.fn.touchTouch = function(){

  var placeholders = $([]),
  index = 0,
  items = this;
  // Appending the markup to the page
  overlay.hide().appendTo('body');
  slider.appendTo(overlay);

  // Creating a placeholder for each image
  items.each(function(){
    placeholders = placeholders.add($('<div class="placeholder">'));
});

...
```

If someone could help me to find a way to make it work also for the first time this would be nice ...

Answer (score 0):

At this point I nearly get what I wanted but there is a bug in my code and I can't see where it does come from.

The solution I have chosen is to introduce a new class MyCat and my modifications try to make sure that this class is only present if the image corresponds to the current category and that the jquery takes in account this class.

Here's the description of this bug :
This happens when first I filter on a category with x images, navigate through them and get out of navigation on the last image.
Then I filter on a category with less than x images, lets say y. 
Now when I click on the image I get no image or in some cases a bad image) and I need to click on the previous image link (y-x) times to get the right image. Note that at this time the system stabilized because now the next image link is not available.

I hope thet my description is understandable if not let me know.
I don't know if there is a more elegant way to do this but as it nearly works please let me know if you see something that could explain the bug.

Here is the code of the 2 important files I modified :

gallery.php :

```
...
<?php if((!empty($this->lead_items) || (!empty($this->intro_items))) &&  $this->params->get('show_filter')): ?>
      <div class="filters">


        <ul id="filters" class="unstyled">
          <li><a href="#" data-filter="*" class="selected"><?php echo JText::_('TPL_COM_CONTENT_GALLERY_FILTER_SHOW_ALL'); ?></a></li>
          <?php 
            foreach ($galleryCategories as $key => $value) : 
          ?>
          <li><a class="" href="#"data-filter=".<?php echo special_chars_replace($value); ?>"><?php echo ucwords(str_replace("_"," ",$value)); ?></a></li>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
<?php endif; ?>
...
<div class="row-fluid">
  <ul id="isotopeContainer" class="gallery items-row cols-<?php echo (int) $this->columns;?>">
    <?php 
        $valgtr = array();
        $keysgtr = array_keys($this->intro_items);
        shuffle($keysgtr);
        foreach($keysgtr as $keygtr) $valgtr[] = $this->intro_items[$keygtr];

        foreach ($valgtr as $key => &$item) : 
    ?>
    <?php
      $key = ($key - $leadingcount) + 1;
      $rowcount = (((int) $key - 1) % (int) $this->columns) + 1;

      if ($rowcount == 1) : ?>    
      <?php endif; ?>

        <li class="gallery-item <?php echo special_chars_replace(strtolower(str_replace(" ","_",$item->category_title))); ?>">
            <?php
            $this->item = &$item;
            echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
... 
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  (function($){ 
   $(window).load(function(){
    var $cols = <?php echo $this->columns; ?>;
    var $container = $('#isotopeContainer');

    $item = $('.gallery-item')
    $item.outerWidth(Math.floor($container.width() / $cols));

    $container.isotope({
      animationEngine: 'best-available',
      animationOptions: {
          queue: false,
          duration: 800
        },
        containerClass : 'isotope',
        containerStyle: {
          position: 'relative',
          overflow: 'hidden'
        },
        hiddenClass : 'isotope-hidden',
        itemClass : 'isotope-item',
        resizable: true,
        resizesContainer : true,
        transformsEnabled: !$.browser.opera // disable transforms in Opera
    });

    if($container.width() <= '767'){
      $item.outerWidth($container.width());
      $item.addClass('straightDown');
      $container.isotope({
        layoutMode: 'straightDown'
      });
    } else {
      $item.removeClass('straightDown');
      $container.isotope({
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
      });
    }

    $(window).resize(function(){
      $item.outerWidth(Math.floor($container.width() / $cols));
      if($container.width() <= '767'){
        $item.outerWidth($container.width());
        $item.addClass('straightDown');
        $container.isotope({
          layoutMode: 'straightDown'
        });
      } else {
        $item.outerWidth(Math.floor($container.width() / $cols));
        $item.removeClass('straightDown');
        $container.isotope({
          layoutMode: 'fitRows'
        });
      }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
}); 
</script>

<?php if($this->params->get('show_filter')): ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  (function($){ 
   $(window).load(function(){
    var $container = $('#isotopeContainer');

    // filter items when filter link is clicked
    $('#filters a').click(function(){
      var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
      $container.isotope({ filter: selector });
      if(selector == "*"){
        $(".touchGalleryLink").addClass("MyCat");
      } else { 
        $(".touchGalleryLink").removeClass("MyCat");
        $(".touchGalleryLink").each(function() {
          var tmpvar = $(this).parent().parent().attr('class').split(" ",2);
          if(tmpvar[1] == selector.substr(1)){
            $(this).addClass("MyCat");
        }
      });
    }
    jQuery('a.touchGalleryLink.MyCat').touchTouch();
    return false;
  });
  $( "#filters a:first" ).trigger( "click" );

  var $optionSets = $('#filters li'),
      $optionLinks = $optionSets.find('a');

      $optionLinks.click(function(){
          var $this = $(this);
          // don't proceed if already selected
          if ( $this.hasClass('selected') ) {
            return false;
          }
          var $optionSet = $this.parents('#filters');
          $optionSet.find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
          $this.addClass('selected');

          // make option object dynamically, i.e. { filter: '.my-filter-class' }
          var options = {},
              key = $optionSet.attr('data-option-key'),
              value = $this.attr('data-option-value');
          // parse 'false' as false boolean
          value = value === 'false' ? false : value;
          options[ key ] = value;
          if ( key === 'layoutMode' && typeof changeLayoutMode === 'function' ) {
            // changes in layout modes need extra logic
            changeLayoutMode( $this, options )
          } else {
            // otherwise, apply new options
            $container.isotope( options );
          }

          return false;
      });
  });
})(jQuery);
}); 
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

touch.gallery.js :

```
(function($){

  /* Private variables */
  var overlay = $('<div id="galleryOverlay">'),
    slider = $('<div id="gallerySlider">'),
    prevArrow = $('<a id="prevArrow"></a>'),
    nextArrow = $('<a id="nextArrow"></a>'),
    overlayVisible = false;


/* Creating the plugin */

$.fn.touchTouch = function(){

    var placeholders = $([]),
        index = 0,
        items = this;
        gtritems = items;
        $.each(gtritems, function() {
          if(!$(this).hasClass("MyCat")){
            $(this).remove();
          }
        });
        console.log(gtritems);
    // Appending the markup to the page
    overlay.hide().appendTo('body');
    slider.appendTo(overlay);

    // Creating a placeholder for each image
    gtritems.each(function(){
      placeholders = placeholders.add($('<div class="placeholder">'));
    });

    $("#gallerySlider").empty();
    // Hide the gallery if the background is touched / clicked
    slider.append(placeholders).on('click',function(e){
      if(!$(e.target).is('img')){
        hideOverlay();
      }
    });

    // Listen for touch events on the body and check if they
    // originated in #gallerySlider img - the images in the slider.
    $('body').on('touchstart', '#gallerySlider img', function(e){

      var touch = e.originalEvent,
      startX = touch.changedTouches[0].pageX;

      slider.on('touchmove',function(e){

      e.preventDefault();

        touch = e.originalEvent.touches[0] ||
          e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0];

        if(touch.pageX - startX > 10){
          slider.off('touchmove');
          showPrevious();
        }
        else if (touch.pageX - startX < -10){
          slider.off('touchmove');
          showNext();
          }
        });

        // Return false to prevent image 
        // highlighting on Android
        return false;

    }).on('touchend',function(){
        slider.off('touchmove');
    });

    // Listening for clicks on the thumbnails

    gtritems.on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      // Find the position of this image
      // in the collection

      index = gtritems.index(this);
      console.log(this);
      showOverlay(index);
      showImage(index);

      // Preload the next image
      preload(index+1);

      // Preload the previous
      preload(index-1);

    });

    // If the browser does not have support 
    // for touch, display the arrows
    if ( !("ontouchstart" in window) ){
      overlay.append(prevArrow).append(nextArrow);

      prevArrow.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        showPrevious();
      });

      nextArrow.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        showNext();
      });
    }

    // Listen for arrow keys
    $(window).bind('keydown', function(e){

      if (e.keyCode == 37){
        showPrevious();
      }
      else if (e.keyCode==39){
        showNext();
      }

    });


    /* Private functions */


    function showOverlay(index){

      // If the overlay is already shown, exit
      if (overlayVisible){
        return false;
      }

      // Show the overlay
      overlay.show();

      setTimeout(function(){
        // Trigger the opacity CSS transition
        overlay.addClass('visible');
      }, 100);

      // Move the slider to the correct image
      offsetSlider(index);

      // Raise the visible flag
      overlayVisible = true;
    }

    function hideOverlay(){
      // If the overlay is not shown, exit
      if(!overlayVisible){
        return false;
      }

      // Hide the overlay
      overlay.hide().removeClass('visible');
      overlayVisible = false;
    }

    function offsetSlider(index){
      // This will trigger a smooth css transition
      slider.css('left',(-index*100)+'%');
    }

    // Preload an image by its index in the items array
    function preload(index){
      setTimeout(function(){
        showImage(index);
      }, 1000);
    }

    // Show image in the slider
    function showImage(index){

      // If the index is outside the bonds of the array
      if(index < 0 || index >= gtritems.length){
        return false;
      }

      // Call the load function with the href attribute of the item
      loadImage(gtritems.eq(index).attr('href'), function(){
        placeholders.eq(index).html(this);
      });
    }

    // Load the image and execute a callback function.
    // Returns a jQuery object

    function loadImage(src, callback){
      var img = $('<img>').on('load', function(){
      callback.call(img);
      });

      img.attr('src',src);
      }

      function showNext(){

        // If this is not the last image
        if(index+1 < gtritems.length){
          index++;
          offsetSlider(index);
          preload(index+1);
        }
        else{
          // Trigger the spring animation

          slider.addClass('rightSpring');
          setTimeout(function(){
            slider.removeClass('rightSpring');
          },500);
        }
      }

    function showPrevious(){

      // If this is not the first image
      if(index>0){
        index--;
        offsetSlider(index);
        preload(index-1);
      }
      else{
        // Trigger the spring animation

        slider.addClass('leftSpring');
        setTimeout(function(){
          slider.removeClass('leftSpring');
        },500);
      }
    }
};

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly not a jquery expert
For my understanding at this time I think the bug of my solution comes from the fact that I had to move the call of the touchtouch function FROM the script.js file loaded 1 time at page loading time TO the filter click function executed whenever the filter changes.
Because I observed the variable gtritems in the console and can see that each time I filter I'm adding something like a new occurence and the accumulation of all this seems to provoke the error.
Is there a way to cleanup the old occurences so that when I call :

```
jQuery('a.touchGalleryLink.MyCat').touchTouch();
```

there is a new clean code executed ?
Some help would really be appreciated !